# return page name in url

Tags: pages, urls

This the url format: `www.mysite.com/pageone`

How do I get the page name? what is the wordpress function/method for this?

bloginfo('name') return the site name. I want the function that returns (return not echo) the name of the current page.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to get from what input. Page's title from page's URL? Page slug from something? Please write it out more clearly.

Comment: @Rarst: I clarified my question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display title of current page you use [`the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) template tag.

Related and slightly more specific functions are:

- [`get_the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_the_title) that returns title without echoing and can retrieve title of another page/post, given its ID as input;
- [`the_title_attribute()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_title_attribute) that returns a little more cleaned up version (safer to use in link titles without breaking markup and such) and takes arguments in query string format.

Comment: Or maybe even `get_query_var('pagename')`?

Comment: @t31os if I am not mistaken that would be slug and not title.

Comment: Oh yes of course, my bad...